# Fallo al instalar APK en android 7.0.0 (INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED)

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

[image: Error]
Al intentar instalar mi proyecto de android, me da error en el archivo XML.
Al instalarlo en android 8.0 (API 26), se me instala sin problemas, pero al instalar en android 7.0 (API 24), me sale este error de arriba.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="RubenPX.ROX">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".Main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Desinstala la aplicación antes de lanzarla, esto es porque la aplicacion esta compilada en el teléfono con una versión superior a la que estas tratando de instalar.

Comment: La aplicación en el teléfono, no la tenia instalada, de hecho, nunca se ha llegado a instalar

Comment: También puedes probar cambiando el nombre del paquete a package="rubenpx.rox" todo en minusculas

Comment: seguro que tu clase se llama Main?

Comment: @TheVicShow Tu respuesta ha funcionado perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

El error `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED` regularmente se debe a dos causas:

> - Los tags no son cerrados correctamente.
> - Existe una propiedad que tiene un valor incorrecto o no existe

Puedes utilizar [lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint) para revisar si tu `AndroidManifest.xml` es correcto

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint

Revisando el error desplegado en el mensaje, indica :

> `<activity>` does not have a valid `android:name`

esto se debe a dos causas:

> - La clase especificada no existe. Asegura que el nombre de la clase es correcto y existe.
> - El paquete que contiene la clase es incorrecto. Asegura que el paquete sea correcto y contenga dentro la clase especificadad en `<activity android:name=".Main">`